# how to change the picture on a page without a button or without hovering over it

Tags: javascript, html, image, animation

I have to make a program which is able to present an animation once opened.

Here the code that I have so far, but I am not sure how to fix it to automatically show the pictures and I am not allowed to use a button or hover over the image to change it , and I'm not allowed to  use a premade gif or a gif at all

```js
var index = 0;
var ImageList = ["http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/happy-256.png", "http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/sad-256.png"];
var image1 = document.getElementById("myImage");

function onTimer() {
  timerValue++;
  para.innerHTML = timerValue;
  if (timerValue >= 30) {
    img.src("http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/happy-256.png");
  } else if (timer <= 60) {
    img.src("http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/sad-256.png");
  } else {
    img.src("http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/happy-256.png");
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/happy-256.png" style="width:200px">
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `setInterval()` function?

Comment: Why downvotes? If you don't know about `setInterval` it's very hard to find how it works.

Comment: I made you a snippet to present a formatted  [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interval:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var index = 0;
   var ImageList = ["Images/happy.png", "Images/sad.png"];
   var image1 = document.getElementById("myImage");
   var a = 0;
   setInterval(function(){
       a++;
       image1.src = ImageList[a % ImageList.length];
      }, 30000);
   }
```

It changes the image per 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two images in an array. USE it!

```js
var index = 0;
var ImageList = ["http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/happy-256.png", "http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/sad-256.png"];

window.onload=function() { // page has finished loading, image is available
  var image1 = document.getElementById("myImage");
  var tId=setInterval(function() {
    index=index==0?1:0; // if 0 then 1 else 0
    // for more images instead use: 
    // index++; if (index>=ImageList.length)index=0;
    image1.src=ImageList[index]; // how to set the image src
  },5000); // every 5 seconds
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/orange/happy-256.png" style="width:200px">
```